# mod_rewrite not working after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apache2

I'm hoping this is a quick and simple fix and that I just need a fresh set of eyes. However, I'm fearful that it might actually be an error in the latest build of the rewrite module.

I have a .htaccess file that turns on the rewrite engine (I've made sure the module is enabled), creates some rewrite conditions, and finally a rewrite rule. Here's my .htaccess file for reference:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Now for the problem: if I go to hostname.com it works fine. If I go to hostname.com/Index it works fine. However, if I go to hostname.com/index it doesn't rewrite the request and I get a 404. I'm not sure what's going on here. I've used a rewrite rule tester and there doesn't appear to be any issues with my rewrite rule itself.

Again, this issue didn't manifest until after I upgraded to 12.10, at which point I know that Apache was updated.

Any thoughts? Has anyone else here experienced this? I know that two other people besides myself have experienced this [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073232).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Try to disable and enable it again with `a2dismod mod_rewrite` and `a2enmod mod_rewrite`. Restart apache afterwards: `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Still the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. All I had to do was edit my virtual host and remove "Multiviews" from my options.

Old:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
```

New:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

And then it worked!